# Accordian not working inside templateurl

Tags: angularjs

When my new html renedered from Admin.html inside accordian control is not working

```
angular.module('TabsApp', [])
.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope)
{ 
    $scope.tabs = [{
    title: 'Admin',
    templateUrl: 'Views/Admin.html'
},
{
    title: 'Data',
    templateUrl: 'two.tpl.html'
},
{
    title: 'Chart',
    templateUrl: 'three.tpl.html'
},
{
    title: 'DashBoard',
    templateUrl: 'four.tpl.html'
}];
$scope.currentTab = 'Views/Admin.html';
$scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {     
    if (tab.title == 'Admin') {
        $scope.currentTab = tab.templateUrl;
    }
    else {
        $scope.currentTab = tab.templateUrl;
    }
}
$scope.isActiveTab = function (tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
}
}]);
```

Comment: Please define *not working*. Could you also put all your code into a `code zone` ?

Comment: Can you post complete code into plunkr/bitbucket or so? I also dont know what you mean by accordian. I suppose, you are using angular-ui/bootstrap (accordion component).

Comment: Thanks Winsik ...now its working  after adding dependency of accordian to main module which am using with ng-app.